# click on a button placed over a video results in unwanted play/stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a wrap and a video and button inside
Click on button results in unwanted play/stop
I want to play/stop video `only` if video is clicked and not any other element inside `wrap`
And keep the button positioned absolute, i.e. on a higher z-index then the video

```
<div class='wrap'>
<video class='vid' src='ph/video.mp4' controls"></video>
<button class='btn'>CLICK</button>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrap{width:540px; position:relative;}
.vid{display:block; width:100%;}
.btn{position:absolute; right:14px; top:9px; z-index:5;}
```

**js**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    console.log('btn clicked');  // doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `stopPropagation` on the event.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('btn clicked');  // doesn't work
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? When I run your code, clicking the video doesn't play/pause unless I click the play button. Or do you have an additional even listener on the vide?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. There is no any other code linked to the button. First click must be on play button - that's ok, but any next click works on video itself.